# Check programatically if Cart or Checkout Blocks are used in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, woocommerce-blocks

How to identify in the backend if the store is using Checkout blocks [classic_checkout] or WooCommerce checkout with shortcode [woocommerce_checkout].

I'm testing a payment gateway and I use enqueue_script to add the JS to the frontend. What is the best way to validate whether a store is using the Blocks-compatible [classic_checkout] block or not, so that scripts can only be queued when necessary?

Comment: Go to checkout edit page and if you see [woocommerce_checkout] in the main editor, is that you are using a shortcode and not blocks.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I need to validate programmatically in the backend, to use wp_enqueue_script only if the store uses checkout blocks.

Comment: As this is related to content added via the main editor, I don't see (or I don't have the way on) how you can check that programmatically in the backend, sorry…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Could using has block('classic_checkout') work?

Comment: I found the way and answered your question below…

Answer (score 5):

I finally found the way via `has_block_in_page( $page, $block_name )` function located in [WC_Blocks_Utils Class](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/8.6/plugins/woocommerce/includes/blocks/class-wc-blocks-utils.php#L62-L84). You can use it for Checkout as follows:

```php
// Conditional function that check if Checkout page use Checkout Blocks
function is_checkout_block() {
    return WC_Blocks_Utils::has_block_in_page( wc_get_page_id('checkout'), 'woocommerce/checkout' );
}
```

For cart page, you can use:

```php
// Conditional function that check if Cart page use Cart Blocks
function is_checkout_block() {
    return WC_Blocks_Utils::has_block_in_page( wc_get_page_id('cart'), 'woocommerce/cart' );
}
```

Tested and works

Answer (score 0):

I tried this approach:

```
function is_checkout_block() {
    $page_to_check = wc_get_page_id ('checkout');
    $content = get_post($page_to_check)->post_content;
    return strpos($content, 'block') !== false;
}
```

this solved the issue for me

**Edit**

At last I found also another solution using CartCheckoutUtils. Here below a sample code:

```
function is_checkout_block() {
    return \Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\Utils\CartCheckoutUtils::is_checkout_block_default();
}
```

I tested also this, and it works.